# How to deal with question that is solved but not correctly answered?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

So I have a question here, solved with help from the answers but not actually answered. Should I leave it unanswered or pick the one that was the closest to my own answer.

Question: [Wait between tasks with SingleThreadExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987395/wait-between-tasks-with-singlethreadexecutor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If none of the answers actually answered your question then it is appropriate that you post the answer you used yourself and then check it as the accepted answer.  It would also be good form to upvote those answers that did help you with your problem and to leave a comment on why it was that they didn't directly answer your questions, maybe just finalizing what you've already mentioned in your comments..